# pyqgis: using gdalogr:rastercalculator not working

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, gdalogr

I have an Int16 - 16 bit GeoTiff and would like to do a simple calculation.
Using the GUI in QGIS (raster calculator) it works without problems. The expression in the raster calculator is: Raster_Image * 0.04 - 273.15

I want to do the calculation via pyqgis. For this I would like to use the process gdalogr: rastercalculator.

I tried the following:

```
import processing
# Get actual raster layer (GeoTiff)
layer = iface.activeLayer();
output = processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', 
                                                layer,         #INPUT_A <ParameterRaster>
                                                '1',         #BAND_A <ParameterString>
                                                None,         #INPUT_B <ParameterRaster>
                                                '',         #BAND_B <ParameterString>
                                                None,        #INPUT_C <ParameterRaster>
                                                '',         #BAND_C <ParameterString>
                                                None,        #INPUT_D <ParameterRaster>
                                                '',         #BAND_D <ParameterString>
                                                None,        #INPUT_E <ParameterRaster>
                                                '',         #BAND_E <ParameterString>
                                                None,        #INPUT_F <ParameterRaster>
                                                '',         #BAND_F <ParameterString>
                                                'A*0.04-273.15', #FORMULA <ParameterString>
                                                '',          #NO_DATA <ParameterString>
                                                '1',           #RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
                                                '',         #EXTRA <ParameterString>
                                                None)        #OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
rLayer= QgsRasterLayer(output['OUTPUT'],'result')
print rLayer.isValid()
```

The calculated raster is not valid. I just do not understand what I'm doing wrong.